# ConvnetJS - best config

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm currently playing around with this: https://github.com/marcoabreu/ConvNetJS-EMG-to-Force

It belongs to deep learning and is about the relation between EMG Signals and the applied force.

```
    layer_defs.push({type:'input', out_sx:windowSize, out_sy:8, out_depth:1});

layer_defs.push({type:'conv', sx:7, filters:16, stride:1, pad:2, activation:'relu'});
layer_defs.push({type:'pool', sx:2, stride:2});
layer_defs.push({type:'conv', sx:5, filters:32, stride:1, pad:2, activation:'relu'});
layer_defs.push({type:'pool', sx:3, stride:3});
layer_defs.push({type:'fc', num_neurons:64, activation: 'relu'});

layer_defs.push({type:'regression', num_neurons:1});

net = new convnetjs.Net();
net.makeLayers(layer_defs);

trainer = new convnetjs.Trainer(net, {method: 'adadelta', learning_rate: 0.01, l2_decay: 0.001, batch_size: 5})
```

This is the default config. What would you suggest to change to get the best amount accuracy? Which layers should I add, how many filters should I use?

Any suggestions here?

Comment: Sorry but this question is completely unanswerable, as it depends on your data, and basically the only way to find out is to do trial and error.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro the data is the dataset that is lying under the github repository. Ofcourse, you can't suggest a "perfect solution" but I'm sure there are some tricks like using many layers, but not too many (to not make it too small), how many filters, the best method, a good learning rate, etc.... I'm sure there are lots of experiences that somebody can share.

Comment: The only trick one can suggest is to use many layers, but how many? nobody knows, for the rest nobody can suggest you actual values, there are only heuristics, but then that advice is quite generic and might not apply to your question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro the actual values that my network is trained with are those: https://github.com/marcoabreu/ConvNetJS-EMG-to-Force/blob/master/dataset/emgdata_final_trainingset.csv 

would you say it is better to use many layers with less filters or less layers but with more filters? are there any suggestions on the learning rate or the input? Or about the sx and sy values? There are 10 rows and about 50k lines in the csv file that I'm training it with...